# Using several fields on the same level in pivottabler

Tags: r, pivot-table

I'm looking in `pivottabler` for the option to build the table for 2 parallel fields, like that:

```
             SEX      |             POPULATION GROUPS
______________________|_______________________________________  
    1       |   2     |   1     |   2     |   3     |   4
 ___________|_________|_________|_________|_________|___________
  AgeGroups |AgeGroups|AgeGroups|AgeGroups|AgeGroups|AgeGroups            
      |  |  |   |  |  |   |  |  |   |  |  |   |  |  |   |  |     
    1 | 2| 3| 1 | 2| 3| 1 | 2| 3| 1 |2 | 3| 1 | 2| 3| 1 | 2| 3
______|__|__|___|__|__|___|__|__|___|__|__|___|__|__|___|__|___
      |  |  |   |  |  |   |  |  |   |  |  |   |  |  |   |  |
```

How can I add in `AddColumnDataRows` 2 or more fields parallel and not hierarchically?

Comment: please try again with the table. use codeblocks starting and ending with three ` (backticks). In there, mono-spaced font will be used. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by specifying `atLevel=1` when adding the population group columns to the pivot table.

I have made up some sample data to use in an example below.

```
n <- 100
sex <- sample(x=c("M","F"), size=n, replace=TRUE)
pg <- sample(x=c("pg1","pg2","pg3","pg4"), size=n, replace=TRUE)
ag <- sample(x=c("ag1","ag2","ag3"), size=n, replace=TRUE)
grp <- sample(x=c("g1","g2","g3","g4"), size=n, replace=TRUE)
df <- data.frame(sex, pg, ag, grp)

library(pivottabler)
pt <- PivotTable$new()
pt$addData(df) 
pt$addColumnDataGroups("sex", addTotal=FALSE)
pt$addColumnDataGroups("pg", atLevel=1, addTotal=FALSE)
pt$addColumnDataGroups("ag", addTotal=FALSE)
pt$addRowDataGroups("grp")
pt$defineCalculation(calculationName="Count", summariseExpression="n()")
pt$renderPivot()
```

Example output:

[image: example output]

Hope that helps

Chris